# Getting error when trying to access excel file stored in cloud storage bucket from dag file of cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to read data from excel stored in google cloud storage bucket.Below is the source code.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime,re,os,io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gcsfs
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from spam import SPAM as spam


yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today() - 
datetime.timedelta(1),
datetime.datetime.min.time())

default_dag_args = {
  'start_date': yesterday,
  'retries': 1,
  'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
  'project_id': models.Variable.get('gcp_project')
}
with models.DAG(
    'first_pipeline',
    # Continue to run DAG once per day
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
def data_load():
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='gcp_project')
    updated_file_list = fs.ls('/us-****-first-pipeline-****- 
bucket/dags/spam/')
    data = pd.read_excel(r"updated_file_list/Book1.xlsx")
    data_nodup = 
data.drop_duplicates(keep='first').dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    data_nodup = data_nodup.drop(data_nodup.index[data_nodup['Long Review'] 
== 1])
    logging.info('Data length',len(data_nodup))
    logging.info('Data loading completed')

data_load = python_operator.PythonOperator(
    task_id='data_load',
    python_callable=data_load)
```

The full orchestration is yet to be completed.I was trying to upload data to storage first.

Below is the error I am getting.

**Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/first_pipeline_dag.py] Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.**

I have provided highest permission to my service account and made the bucket public but still getting the same error.

Could you please help me to check configuration I may have missed.

Your suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the service account has the required permissions, it seems that it is not being included within your script.

Take a look at the [GCSFS documentation](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials). It is said that if No authentication method is set, it will take the Anonymous access which matches with your scenario.

On that same doc you can find several authentication methods, such as using "cloud" or the JSON credentials file as *token*. Following the [GCSFS API docs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gcsfs.core.GCSFileSystem), the *token* argument must be set when creating your Class. It should look like this:

```
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='gcp_project', token='path/to/my/credentials.json')
```

After that, the credentials should be set for the Service Account linked to the JSON file and the access should be granted.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the GCSFS library is on Beta stage by now so it may have some issues on it.

Comment: Thanks for responding Kevin.I have followed your step to include application default credentials.json.But the issue remains.I am getting below response an airflow dashboard now."Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/first_pipeline_dag.py] /us-east4-gcs-access-03dd50c5-bucket/data/adc.json".

Comment: As you mentioned,I have added the URLs while creating the environment.The below URLs are visible in the scope of env conf now.

Google API scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.

Could you please provide an example of sharing the drive file with the service account?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Drive to the scope of your Composer instance. Unfortunately you cannot edit the scope, you must include them when creating an instance.
If using `gcloud` to create instances include the below as a parameter:

```
--oauth-scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

If using the web UI you should specify like this on the creation page:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding Parakeet.I have created environment newly and added the drives in the oauth scopes.Unfortunately,the issue remains.

Comment: @AnandaRoy Have you shared the Drive file with the service account running the new Composer instance?